# Rigid non-archimedean real closed fields

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra, lo.logic, model-theory, real-algebraic-geometry, infinitesimals

> **Question.** *Is there a **countable** rigid non-Archimedean real closed field*?

**Background:**

1. As usual, a structure is said to be *rigid* if the only automorphism of the structure is the identity map.
2. It is well-known that any Archimedean ordered field is rigid; the argument is the same as that used by Darboux in 1880 to prove that the field of real numbers is rigid. Note that the Archimedean ordered fields are precisely those ordered fields that are isomorphic a subfield of the field of real numbers.
3. In 1983 Shelah showed that its consistent with the axioms of set theory (ZFC) that there is an *uncountable* rigid non-Archimedean closed field. Here is the reference: *Shelah, Saharon, Models with second order properties. IV. A general method and eliminating diamonds. Ann. Pure Appl. Logic 25 (1983), no. 2, 183–212.*
4. Using machinery from the metamathematics of arithmetic, one can build (many) countable rigid non-Archimedean ordered fields. More specifically: it is well-known that countable nonstandard rigid models of PA exist (this is independently due to Gaifman and Ehrenfeucht). Let $\cal{M}$ be such a model, and let $\mathbb{Q}^{\cal{M}}$ be the field of rationals as computed in $\cal{M}$. By a classical theorem of Julia Robinson, $\cal{M}$ and $\mathbb{Q}^{\cal{M}}$ are bi-interpretable, therefore $\mathbb{Q}^{\cal{M}}$ is also rigid. One can use the same type of argument to show that there are (many) rigid non-Archimedean ordered fields in every infinite cardinality.

Comment: What if you consider the real-closure of the field $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathcal{M}}$ mentioned in statement 4? The model $\mathcal{M}$ can undertake the real-closure construction. Perhaps the resulting field is also bi-interpretable with $\mathcal{M}$?

Comment: @JoelDavidHamkins I thought about that strategy but real closed fields tend to be very poor in their power to interpret due to lack of coding machinery (and very well-behaved definable sets), for example even though the standard model of arithmetic can interpret the field of algebraic numbers (which forms a real closed field),  the latter cannot interpret the former, since the theory of algebraic numbers is the same as the theory of real closed fields, which is a decidable theory, but of the course the Turing degree of theory of the standard model of arithmetic is the $\omega$-th jump of $0$.

Comment: Yes, I see. Perhaps one can show rigidity without showing the bi-interpretability? It would of course suffice to show that automorphisms of the real-closure of $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathcal{M}}$ respect $\mathbb{Q}^{\mathcal{M}}$. I wonder if there is any way for us to see that?

Comment: The real closure of a countable model of PA is recursively saturated, thus homogeneous. It will have lots of automorphisms.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Bingo!

Comment: Given a countable non-Archimedean real-closed field $F$, with an infinitesimal $t$, can we prove that some automorphism of $F$ extends the ring automorphism $\mathbb{Q}[t]\to\mathbb{Q}[2t]$? That would answer the posted question in the negative.

Comment: @MattF. I don't know the answer to your question. Why not pose it as a new question ?(with a pointer this question).

Comment: @MattF. I very much doubt this is true in general (though the following is not a finished proof). Let $K$ be the completion of the real closure of $\mathbb Q(t)$ with $t>0$ infinitesimal; $K$ can be described as the field of Levi-Civita series $\sum_{q\in\mathbb Q}a_qt^q$ where $a_q$ are real algebraic, and $\{q:a_q\ne0\}$ has no accumulation point other than $+\infty$. Let $u=\sum_qa_qt^q$ be such a series, and $F$ be the real closure of $\{t,u\}$ in $K$. Then if $F$ has an automorphism mapping $t$ to $2t$, it must map $u$ to $u'=\sum_qa_q2^qt^q$. But if $u$ is sufficiently complicated, ...

Comment: ... then $u'$ should not be algebraic over $\{t,u\}$, i.e., it should not be an element of $F$, and such an automorphism should not exist.

Comment: Does the real-algebraic closure of $\{t,Li_2(t)=\sum t^n/n^2\}$ (in the Levi-Civita field $\mathcal{R}$) give a positive answer to the original question? That is the example that comes to mind from working through @EmilJeřábek’s counterargument to my proposed counterargument. It seems promising that the Wolfram functions site lists no algebraic identities between $Li_2(t)$ and $Li_2(t’)$ with $t$ and $t’$ which could both be positive infinitesimals: https://functions.wolfram.com/ZetaFunctionsandPolylogarithms/PolyLog2/17/ShowAll.html

Comment: In other words: Is it possible to have positive infinitesimal $t\neq u$ in the Levi-Civita field $\mathcal{R}$ and non-zero polynomials $p,q\in \mathbb{Q}[x,y,z]$ such that $p(t, Li_2(t), u)$ and $q(t, Li_2(t), Li_2(u))$ are both zero? Here $Li_2(x)=\sum x^n/n^2$. A negative answer to this gives a positive answer to the posted question, using the example in the previous comment.